# Returning to Original Page with success Mesaage. Boostramp + PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to make it so when the user enters my contact form instead of being redirected to the "mail.php" file they are just shown a message which shows that the message has been sent successfully on the same page. I have tried many tutorials with JS and I am still not sure how to do this.

The PHP Mailer and the Html work, its just the javascript that is meant to show the users the success or failure message which isn't working.

I originally tried to put the JS in a different file and then just call it as a different script at the bottom of the page below jQuery, but this did not work I will probably move it back to its own file.

My HTML currently looks like

```
<div class="form-container">
    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="mail.php" name="contact-form" role="form" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right: 4px;">
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 4px;">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter valid email address.')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Why are you contacting me?" required />
        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Tell me more about your propersition?" required></textarea>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            <label class="checkbox-label">
                <input type="checkbox" id="tos" name="tos" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please read the Terms of Service.')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" required>
                <span class="checkbox-custom rectangular"></span>
            </label>
            <label for="tos">I agree to the <a href="tos.php">Terms of Service</a></label>
    </form>
</div>
```

My PHP mailer file (Mail.php) currently looks like

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'mail.edbrook.site';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'info@edbrook.site';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('info@edbrook.site', 'Web Contact');
    $mail->addAddress('ed@edbrook.site', 'Admin - Edbrook.site');     // Add a recipient

    // message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
    $okMessage = 'Thank you for your message. We will get back to you soon!';

    // If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
    $errorMessage = 'There was an error. Please try again later!';

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Contact Form Message';
    $mail->Body    = "Full Name: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['first_name'])."<br />Email Address: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])."<br /><br />";

    $mail->send();
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
} catch (Error $e) {
    // should log the fatal
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

And the javascript currently looks like

```
            $(function () {
                $('#contact-form').validator();

                $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
                    // if the validator good
                    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                        var url = "mail.php";
                        // POST values in the background the the script URL
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: url,
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            success: function (data)
                            {
                                // data = JSON object that contact.php returns
                                // apply success/danger
                                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                                var messageText = data.message;

                                // Bootstrap alert box HTML
                                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                                // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                                    // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                                    $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                                    // empty the form
                                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                console.error('The ajax request failed:' + errorThrown);
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                })
            });
```

It is mainly copied from online but I do not really need a validator as its already handled within jQuery so doesn't need to be done again I just need the error/success message to be shown on the contact.php page rather than it being redirected to a blank page.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fully working code you. There are few issues in your `ajax` and `HTML`

1. You need set `dataType: json` in your `$.ajax` request because the response you are getting back from the PHP file is json format.
2. Your HTML does not contain any `.messages` div where a success or error message will be displayed
3. In addition you need to use this => `$('#contact-form').submit(function(e){})` for `form` submission and use `e.preventDefault()` to make sure that page does not reload on `form` submission

I assume that your `PHPMailer` is working perfectly and is sending email already. You just need to use this following HTML and `jQuery` code so that the success message is displayed on the `contant.php` pages rather then on another page.

I have tested my code on `localHost` and is working perfectly and sending `email` with the correct form information `data` as well.

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var url = "mail.php";
    //POST values in the background the the script URL
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        // data = JSON object that contact.php returns
        // apply success/danger
        var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
        var messageText = data.message
        // Bootstrap alert box HTML
        var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>'
        // If we have messageAlert and messageText
        if (messageAlert && messageText) {
          // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
          $('.form-container').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
          // empty the form
          $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
        }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('The ajax request failed:' + errorThrown);
      }
    });
    return false;
  })
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-container">
  <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="mail.php" name="contact-form" role="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right: 4px;">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 4px;">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter valid email address.')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Why are you contacting me?" required />
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Tell me more about your propersition?" required></textarea>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    <label class="checkbox-label">
                <input type="checkbox" id="tos" name="tos" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please read the Terms of Service.')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" required>
                <span class="checkbox-custom rectangular"></span>
            </label>
    <label for="tos">I agree to the <a href="tos.php">Terms of Service</a></label>
  </form>
  <div class="messages"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things you need to change.

1. If you do not want to redirect to mail.php, then remove it from the form's `action` attribute. Since you are injecting success/failure message via JavaScript, add `onsubmit="return false;"` so prevent page refresh.

   ```
   <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="" name="contact-form" role="form" onsubmit="return false;">
   ```
2. I can't see a div with class name as `messages` in your HTML.

Comment: now when entering data and clicking submit absolutely nothing happens, and the form doesn't get submitted.

Comment: You don't need a form submission. First check in the browser console if your `AJAX` is firing or not. Secondly, did you add a div with class as `messages`?

Comment: What do you mean i dont need a form submission? There is a submit button that they have to click?

Comment: The Ajaxz is not firing. i was getting a error regarding the Verification but I removed it and then I inouted a console.log above the ajax to see if the js was running it was but the Ajax is not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `e.preventDefault()` Inside

```js
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // here
```

2. Add a new `<div>` inside `<form>` tag:

```html
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="mail.php" name="contact-form" role="form" >
    <div class="messages"></div>
```

Comment: This still redirects me to the Mail.php page.

Comment: Try to use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`instead